# How do I add volumes in Docker for MERN stack app?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mern

I have no knowledge in building Docker yet, but I was reading some documentations and trying to figure out how to create a container for my project. I also don't have too much knowledge in MERN stack.

The images and container are creating just fine, but I am not being able to create in a way that I don’t have to rebuild the application every time a change is made to the application’s source code.

I would like that every time I make a change in the code, it reflects automatically in the link provided by Docker. Instead of building the image again with the new changes.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my app tree:

```
└───Docstree
    │   docker-compose.yml
    │
    ├───DocsTree-Backend
    │   │   .env
    │   │   .gitignore
    │   │   Dockerfile
    │   │   index.js
    │   │   nodesource_setup.sh
    │   │   package-lock.json
    │   │   package.json
    │   │   README.md
    │   │
    │   ├───controllers
    │   ├───html_to_send_by_email
    │   ├───Maildir
    │   ├───middleware
    │   ├───misc
    │   ├───models
    │   ├───node_modules
    │   ├───routes
    │   ├───uploads
    │   └───utils
    └───DocsTree-Frontend
        │   .gitignore
        │   Dockerfile
        │   package-lock.json
        │   package.json
        │   postcss.config.js
        │   README.md
        │   tailwind.config.js
        │   virtualmin-install.log
        │   yarn.lock
        │
        ├───node_modules
        ├───public
        └───src
```

This is my Dockerfile for frontend:

```
FROM node:16.16.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -f
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This is my Dockerfile for backend:

```
FROM node:16.16.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -f
RUN npm install -g nodemon
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["nodemon", "run", "index.js"]
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./DocsTree-Backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - my-app-network

  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - backend
    build:
      context: ./DocsTree-Frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: frontend
    volumes:
      - ./DocsTree-Frontend:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules    
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - my-app-network

networks:
  my-app-network:

volumes:
    node_modules:
```

Comment: For day-to-day development, I wouldn't involve Docker at all.  Just run Node directly on your host system (installing it is probably a one-liner) and run the `nodemon` command you show.  In the Compose file, delete the `volumes:` blocks, which for example prevent you from seeing updates to the `package.json` file.  Use `docker-compose build; docker-compose up -d` when you need to run the whole system.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But I am interested in why? My current is to no install node directly and use Docker for this purpose only, besides being able to run this anywhere. Do you know why am I not being to see the changes "live" tho?

Answer (score 0):

For development, you don't need to create any image. Just use the base `node` image and mount the source codes as volumes. Like so:

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    image: node:16.16.0-alpine
    container_name: backend
    volumes:
      - ./DocsTree-Backend:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command:
      - nodemon
      - index.js
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - my-app-network

  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - backend
    image: node:16.16.0-alpine
    container_name: frontend
    volumes:
      - ./DocsTree-Frontend:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command:
      - npm
      - start
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - my-app-network

  npm:
    image: node:16.16.0-alpine
    entrypoint:
      - npm
    networks:
      - my-app-network

networks:
  my-app-network:
```

This is how I usually set up my projects.

> `npm` commands should be run like `docker compose run --rm npm <command> <--options>`.

> Make sure to install `nodemon` as dev deps of the backend project.

Comment: You mean, there is no need to have `Dockerfile` under Frontend and Backend folders, keep only `docker-compose.yml` to run?

Comment: Yes, for development only. When you ship it for production, of course you need a `Dockerfile` which only ships production package (i.e. no dev deps inside `node_modules`).

Comment: I am sorry, how do I install `nodemon` as you suggested in your answer? Also, after I used the command `docker-compose up`, I got this log `frontend exited with code 0` (same for backend)

Comment: Good question. I've updated my answer. That should answer both your questions.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work, I tried running the command inside backend project but still got errors and container is not starting.

Comment: Is it possible to share the project as a GitHub repo? I'll get some free time tomorrow to look into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254416/discussion-between-guilherme-matheus-and-msrumon).